# argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable POST запросы

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
@app.route('/transactions/new', methods=['POST'])
def GVO_new_transaction():
    values = request.get_json()

    required = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount']
    if not all(k in values for k in required):
        return 'Missing values', 400

    index = blockchain.GVO_new_transaction(values['sender'], values['recipient'], values['amount'])
    response = {'message': f'Transaction will be added to Block {index}'}
    return jsonify(response), 201
```

Вот скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку в `required` у вас точно список есть, остаётся только вариант, что у вас в `values` лежит `None`. Значит `request.get_json()` выдаёт `None`. Видимо, в запросе `JSON` отсутствует.

Comment: А как мне исправить или добавить то что мне нада ? Не сильно понял про "JSON отсутствует" ?

Comment: @ViskasTube В запросе, который вы обрабатываете, есть JSON? Посмотрите вот этот ответ для примера: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127130/8324991

Comment: Нету. А как его добавить ? пробовал те методы что в примере не помогли.